# Replaced an image in Visual Studio, "Cannot be found" when deployed

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I replaced an image in a SharePoint project in Visual Studio. When I deploy the image cannot be found. I can see it in SharePoint designer, but when I try the url it just gives me an error ("Cannot be found"). It doesn't give me any error message when deploying.

The image is located in a module ("Images").

The only thing that's changed in the picture is the size, it still has the same name and file type.

Why is it behaving like this?

Images/Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Module Name="Images">
     <File Path="Images\customLogo.jpg" Url="Images/customLogo.jpg" />
   </Module>
 </Elements>
```

Comment: Is it being deployed to the filesystem or the content database? If the latter, is there a checked in version, and is it published/approved etc?

Comment: Should the latter matter even if I do a clean install?

Comment: Can you put up the code for your module?

Comment: The module only contains a .jpg file and elements.xml, see update for xml. The module is provisioned with a site feature, the only code there is when the feature is deactivated.

Comment: @RangeRover Probably, unless by "a clean install" you mean "brand new blank content database". SharePoint is a bit bonkers about this stuff sometimes :)

Comment: Oh okay. I mean a clean install of the project, so no not a brand new content database. So the database could be the problem?

Comment: What's the URL at which you're expecting the JPG to be provisioned? It's possible that the Path and URL attributes in the Elements.xml were reset when you replaced the image in Visual Studio.